# Signature image not appearing in sent email

Tags: macos, mail.app, signature

If I create a signature with mac mail and attach a png file to the signature, when I send the email the image appears as a black box on the sent email (examples attached).

In mac mail itself the image appears correctly.

How can I get the image to be sent correctly?

[image: Example received image 1]

[image: Example received image 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right (and best) way to create an HTML signature that includes images:
http://matt.coneybeare.me/how-to-make-and-html-signature-in-apple-mail/